# viewWillDisappear not called after showing iOS Share Sheet

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet, uiactivityviewcontroller

After showing the share sheet and selecting to share via Message something really strange happens with the view lifecycle. When the text message modal pops up neither `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear` fires. I understand that when an app is sent to background (user presses home button) or resumes from a previously active state you don't get view lifecycle delegate method callbacks, but the really strange part is that when you close the Message modal `viewWillAppear` **IS** called.

In this case, the fact that the appear/disappear calls do not balance each other out causes problems for me. Do anyone know of something in the Apple docs that could explain this, or something I may be missing with use of [`UIActivityViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know exactly why you'd get no disappear callback, but *would* get an appear callback, however if it ends up causing anyone else a problem know that you can use `UIActivityViewController`'s completion handler. This will fire when the share sheet dismisses (including both the action sheet as well as full screen modals for example when you share via Message).

```
UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[ shareText, shareUrl ] applicationActivities:nil];
[activityController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
    if (completed) {
        NSLog(@"completed: %@", activityType);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"not completed: %@", activityType);
    }
}];
[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```